# An extension of "if $\mathbb{P}(A_n=B_n) \to 1 $ and $\mathbb{P}(A_n=C_n) \to 1 $, then $\mathbb{P}(B_n=C_n) \to 1$"

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a sequence $X_n$ of vectors of random variables, and I have sets of deterministic functions $a_{m,n}, b_{m,n}, c_{m,n}$ on these vectors that spit out $0$ or $1$.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(a_{1,n}(X_n)=b_{1,n}(X_n), a_{2,n}(X_n)=b_{2,n}(X_n)..., a_{n,n}(X_n)=b_{n,n}(X_n)) = 1$$

I also know that
$$\forall m \in \{1,...,n\}, \mathbb{P}(a_{m,n}(X_n)=c_{m,n}(X_n)) \geq \mathbb{P}(a_{m,n}(X_n)=b_{m,n}(X_n))$$

Can I conclude safely that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(b_{1,n}(X_n)=c_{1,n}(X_n), b_{2,n}(X_n)=c_{2,n}(X_n)..., b_{n,n}(X_n)=c_{n,n}(X_n)) = 1 ?$$

---

Here's why I want this to be true.

If we had the simpler problem with functions $a,b,c$ that spit out $0$ and $1$, and if I knew $\mathbb{P}(a(X_n) = b(X_n)) \to 1$ and $\mathbb{P}(a(X_n) = c(X_n)) \to 1$, then I can immediately say that $\mathbb{P}(b(X_n) = c(X_n))) \to 1$ by virtue of

$$\begin{split} \mathbb{P}(b(X_n) = c(X_n))) & = 1 - \mathbb{P}(b(X_n) \neq c(X_n))) \\& \geq 1 - \mathbb{P}(\text{at least one of } b(X_n) \neq a(X_n)\text{ or } c(X_n) \neq a(X_n) )) \\& \geq 1 - \mathbb{P}(b(X_n) \neq a(X_n)) - \mathbb{P}(c(X_n) \neq a(X_n)) \end{split}$$

Then since $\mathbb{P}(b(X_n) \neq a(X_n))\to 0$ and $\mathbb{P}(c(X_n) \neq a(X_n))\to 0$, I get $\mathbb{P}(b(X_n) = c(X_n))) \to 1$.

---

Here's why I'm a bit confused.

Unlike my toy model above, I'm asking for a relatively strong statement that the intersection of many events has probability that approaches $1$, and I'm not sure that my assumptions are enough to ensure that. It's been a while since I thought rigorously about probability, but I'm hopeful that there might be a quick proof or counterexample to what I'm hoping for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counter-example.  Take $X_n\equiv U$ for $U$ uniform on $[0,1]$.  Divide up the unit interval into $n$ equal subintervals $I_m=[(m-1)/n,m/n]$ and associate with each subinterval an initial $1/n^2$-width "sliver" of that interval, $S_m=[(m-1)/n,(m-1)/n+1/n^2]$.

Now, define the functions:
\begin{align*}
a_{m,n}(u) &= 0\\
b_{m,n}(u) &= 1_{\bigcup S_k}(u)\\
c_{m,n}(u) &= 1_{I_m}(u)
\end{align*}
So, $b_{m,n}\equiv b_n$ is the indicator for the union of all the slivers and $c_{m,n}$ is the indicator for the $m$th subinterval.

We have $\forall m, a_{m,n}(u)=b_{m,n}(u)=0$ except on the slivers, which have total measure $1/n$, so your first condition holds (i.e., the probability is $1-1/n \to 1$.)

For each fixed $m$, we have:
$$P(a_{m,n}(X_n)=c_{m,n}(X_n))=1-P(U\in I_m)=1-1/n$$
and
$$P(a_{m,n}(X_n)=b_{m,n}(X_n))=1-P(U\in \bigcup S_k)=1-1/n$$
so your second condition holds.

Unfortunately for your conjecture, we have $b_{m,n}(u)\not=c_{m,n}(u)$ on $(I_m\setminus S_m) \cup \bigcup_{k\not=m}S_k$, which means that equality fails for at least one $m$ for almost all $u$, so the probability of $\forall m, b_{m,n}(u)=c_{m,n}(u)$ is actually zero.

Comment: Great construction! I like the magic that one of the $c_{m,n}$ is doomed to disagree with $0$, and that though most of the time the $b_{m,n}$ succeed in being zero, the only times they fail are when all of them fail simultaneously.